# Enable Firebase Authentication with Google account in AppGyver

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, google-oauth

How I can enable the authentication using Firebase Authentication with a Google account in AppGyver? I need to my application, but I don’t find any tutorial or something like this, so someone can help me? Basically, what I want is: click on a button and open the popup to user make the login. The account need be save in Firebase too. I should use HTTP request, custom JavaScript, the component WebView or the component HTML renderer? I’m very lost, even reading the most of documentation. I aprecciate the help! PS: I don't find if is possible add libraries in AppGyver, what makes it difficult to implement the codes from Firebase documentation.

Sorry for bad English, by the way.

Comment: Latest info is that they do not support sing in with pop up - AppGyver currently supports the Email/Password and Anonymous type sign-in providers. Choose one or both depending on what you want to use in your app. You can read more here: https://docs.appgyver.com/docs/google-firebase